# Cast Django's intcomma string to Decimal

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to export some records from database with `Django` but when exported the type of `amount` field is represented as `string` and not `decimal`.

> My code

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma
import django_excel as excel


def download(request):
    records = []
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    for reservation in Reservation.objects.sifted(request):
        record['Amount (EUR)'] = intcomma(reservation.amount)
        records.append(record)

    return excel.make_response_from_records(
        records,
        'xls',
        file_name="export_reservations_{}".format(now.strftime('%d_%m_%Y').replace(".",","))
    )
```

> Model

```
amount = DecimalField(max_digits=6,
                          decimal_places=2,
                          null=True,
                          default="0.00",
                          verbose_name='Amount')
```

This produces something like `12.12` which is the correct format but it's string.

If i do `Decimal(intcomma(reservation.amount))`, I get decimal type, but the format is `12` with floating points.

How can I get decimal with correct format(xx.xx) in the export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it really need to be a decimal? Why not just:

```
record['Amount (EUR)'] = round(reservation.amount, 2)
```

Comment: Hm, do you maybe know how would i get `12,12` instead of `12.12`

Comment: As a string, or as a numeric type?

Comment: as numeric tyoe

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: ah your answer actually worked, it was my mistake! thanks :)